# Why when using Riverpod with StateNotifier, setting a (state) field to null, the listeners are not notified?

Tags: flutter, dart, riverpod

So this is a Flutter application using Dart language with the Riverpod package for state management. The intent is that an application has a user if, they are signed in, and is set to null if they are not (or signed out). I found that setting the user to null did not notify the listeners, so I tried with a basic nullable String field, called name. I received the same result.

Example below is for the simple nullable String field. Another thing is, I use the standard data class generator plugin to generate all the boiler plate code such as equality, copywith, hashcode and so on.

So let's assume I have the following using `flutter_riverpod: 2.1.3`

```
class AppSettings {
   User? user;
   String? name;

   AppSettings({
     this.user,
     this.name,
   });

  AppSettings copyWith({
    User? user,
    String? name,
  }) {
    return AppSettings(
      user: user ?? this.user,
      name: name ?? this.name,
    );
  }

 // Additional data class generator methods
 }

 class AppSettingsNotifier extends StateNotifier<AppSettings> {
   AppSettingsNotifier() : super(AppSettings());

   void updateUser(User? user) {
     state = state.copyWith(user: user);
   }

   void updateName(String? name) {
     state = state.copyWith(name: name);
   }
 }

 final appSettingProvider =
     StateNotifierProvider<AppSettingsNotifier, AppSettings>(
    (ref) => AppSettingsNotifier());
```

Then when I set the name field as follows:

`ref.read(appSettingProvider.notifier).updateName(null);`

Then my listeners aren't reacting and the widgets aren't rebuilt.

On the other hand, if I set the name to an actual string:

`ref.read(appSettingProvider.notifier).updateName("Bruce Lee");`

It would instantly update. Even with empty string it will also notify the listeners. So it seems something special is happening with null specifically.

**Why is "null" not causing a notification to listeners?**

**What am I missing here?**

I've tried reading the manual, googling and countless attempts at debugging. Unfortunately, I do not understand enough of the underlying Riverpod/Flutter code to get to the bottom of it.

Comment: Most likely your copyWith implementation doesn't update null value.

Comment: @user18309290 you are right!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By looking at the provided code, So far what I can see a potential issue in your `copyWith` method. Bcz in `flutter`, when using a `copyWith` method the common convention is to keep the instances past data if the data given inside the `copyWith` is `null`.

Right now, it looks like that can be the issue here. So when you pass a null data, The new instance comes with the `name` value from your past object. So try to check if it's the case in your `AppSettings` model class.

Comment: You are where right. I added the offending code for clarity in the future. Thank you for spotting it. Didn't even occur to me that there was something wrong with the generated code. Maybe that is the lesson! 

Comment: You're welcome, bro. And yeah, we live, we learn. Good luck and happy fluttering .

Comment: It's almost impossible to distinguish a missing optional parameter from an explicit null parameter, unless a default value is provided in the formal parameter definition.